# R Change Columns with prefix from factor to character

Tags: r, string, lapply, factors

I have a data frame with factors and characters. I want to change the columns with the column prefix "ID_" to be changed from factors to characters.

I tried the below, but it changes the whole data frame to characters, I just want to change the colnames with "ID_". I don't know how many "ID_" will end up in the data frame (this is part of a larger function that will loop across dataframes with various numbers of "ID_")

```
###Changes the whole dataframe to character rather than only the intended columns

df.loc[] <- lapply(df.loc[, grepl("ID_", colnames(df.loc))], as.character)
```

Comment: In dplyr, `df.loc %>% mutate_at(vars(matches('^ID_')), as.character)`. In base, `id_cols <- grep('^ID_', names(df.loc)); df.loc[id_cols] <- lapply(df.loc[id_cols], as.character)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you assign to the whole data frame with `df.loc[] <-`. Try this:

```
my_cols <- grepl("ID_", colnames(df.loc))
df.loc[my_cols] <- lapply(df.loc[my_cols], as.character)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a tidyverse solution:

```
food <- data_frame(
  "ID_fruits" = factor(c("apple", "banana", "cherry")),
  "vegetables" = factor(c("asparagus", "broccoli", "cabbage")),
  "ID_drinks" = factor(c("absinthe", "beer", "cassis"))
)

food %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("ID_")), as.character)
```

```

Comment: if i use this method the other way arround (with as_factor instead of as.character), it gives an error. The method above from Gregor Thomas gives no error with as_factor.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `ifelse`:

```
df[] <- ifelse(grepl("^ID_", colnames(df)), lapply(df, as.character), df)
```